# Chown operation is not permitted on my pod at openshift

Tags: docker, deployment, openshift, devops

I am trying to deploy a pod on openshift with the base image of tutum/apache-php . We have a requirement of custom php in a particular project. But when the pod is deployed on openshift it shows the error of

chown operation is not permitted

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Hi, I believe you need to add the user in the Root group in order to have  permission.  try the following line in the docker file 
`RUN adduser -u USERID -G root -D USERNAME`

Comment: Thankyou suresh! But this did not work for me !

Comment: You need to replace USERID and USERNAME for example 2000 and suresh

Comment: would be helpful if you add the error and error code as well

Comment: Your image likely expects to run as ``root`` user. Default OpenShift security profile prevents that. If you have cluster admin access for whole OpenShift cluster you can override this if absolutely necessary, but usually is better to use images which don't require to be run as ``root`` user, as that isn't necessarily good practice. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/why-do-my-applications-run-as-a-random-user-id.html and https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html

Comment: Hi Suresh ! Thankyou . I have tried it with username as well. There is a security feature in openshift which prevents it . So the command has no significance .

Comment: For your reference, The error is as follows:  chown: changing ownership of '/app/design/defaulttheme/tpl/lhuser/account/above_account_edit_multiinclude.tpl.php': Operation not permitted

Comment: Thankyou Graham ! I actually don't have access to admin rights. Could you please suggest an image for running a custom PHP project. If you need any project structure, It will be provided to you . Thanking you in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried the PHP image OpenShift provides. https://docs.openshift.com/online/using_images/s2i_images/php.html It uses what is called source to image, so research up about that. Perhaps read free ebook at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/ for background.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Dockerfile to run this command during image build. Inside the Dockerfile you can run the command as root with the following command.

```
USER root
```

Please note that you have to return to normal user priviledges after the command or multiple commands have been executed.

```
USER root
RUN chmod XXX /path/to/file
...
USER 1001
```